# Silverlight ScrollViewer corrupts focus logic

Tags: silverlight, xaml, scrollviewer

My XAML:

```
  <Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0">
      <StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="5" Background="LightGray">
          <TextBlock>Grid1</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock Margin="5">TextBlock1</TextBlock>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">CheckBox1</CheckBox>
        <Button Margin="5">Button1</Button>
      </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
      <Grid Margin="5" Background="LightGray">
        <TextBlock>Grid2</TextBlock>
      </Grid>
      <TextBlock Margin="5">TextBlock2</TextBlock>
      <CheckBox Margin="5">CheckBox2</CheckBox>
      <Button Margin="5">Button2</Button>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

That gives this output:

[image: UI Output]

Here's my problem. If *Button2* has focus clicking on *Grid2* or *TextBlock2* will not change focus. However if *Button1* has focus and clicking on *Grid1* or *TextBlock1*, then focus will be removed from *Button1*. Why? For me it looks like when you surround a panel with a *ScrollViewer* the focus logic is broken.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer you partially...

Is not that `ScrollViewer` breaks focus, when you use a `ScrollViewer` as a container and you click on some place that hasn't a control able to get focus, `ScrollViewer` itself get focus, so to avoid `ScrollViewer` to take focus you can disable the property `IsTabStop` of it.

I tried this, and `ScrollViewer` doesn't get focus when you click on a control without focus handling like a `Grid` or `Textblock`, but focusing is still behaving strange, that's why I said "partially" before.

Set `IsTabStop` to `false` on `ScrollViewer` and see it for yourself...

Also, you can take a look of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964049/getting-a-notification-when-focus-changes-in-silverlight-4) post, where a guy proposed a way to implement a "focus inspector", it's just a few lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for your input. What is not working is: Clicking on Grid1 or TextBlock1, then focus jumps to CheckBox1.